specman agent with configurable number of sub module instances
I have the following Specman agent :
`unit phy_slave_agent_u like uvm_agent {
    !num_of_channels : uint(bits:4);
    monitors : list of phy_slave_monitor_u is instance;
    keep monitors.size() == read_only(num_of_channels);

`
in the run task I get that monitors size is zero although num_of_channels was set before.
Is there a way in  specman to have configurable number of instances?
When I replace "read_only(num_of_channels)" by a number , i.e. 6, then I get monitors size = 6.

the work around for this problem is to set monitors.size in the hierarchy where "num_of_channels" is set.i.e. "unit phy_slave_agent_u" is instantiated in "unit my_env" as "slave". In "unit my_env" i add "keep slave.monitors.size == 6"

num_of_channels is declared as non generatable field by using the exclamation mark (!) in front of it. Hence it is initialized to 0 and NOT randomized.
So the size of the monitors list is constraint to 0, resulting in an empty list.
see also
https://edaplayground.com/x/BsCH
